# Deore FC-M615 single 64 BCD chainring

Tags: gears, crankset, drivetrain

I want to build a 1x9 drivetrain MTB so I'm wondering if I can set this FC-M615 crankset to a single 64 BCD 28T chainring, from what I can see the XT M8000 is compatible and allows 11-speed cassette but I can't find any more information.

Why 28T? because it is what I felt more comfortable with, I have made the gear calculation on [this site](http://gears.mtbcrosscountry.com/#27.5I399I22709X27.5I1371I13714)

Regarding the initial question, is that possible? will it work properly?

Answer (score 1):

You need an offset chainring for this to work well. Otherwise the front chainline will wind up too far in, and when you're riding it with the small cog the chain angle will be extreme and likely problematic, i.e. as though you were crosschaining a double. There's a Wolf Tooth 28t x 64bcd ring that does this. (I'm assuming your frame is either 135 or 142x12; if it's Boost there's not a way for this to work reasonably.)

Presuming you're suggesting using the small ring off a double FC-M8000, that won't work because it's just a normal ring for derailleur use. In addition to not being offset and thereby putting the chainline too far in, it will want to cause rather than prevent derailment in the smaller back cogs when used without an FD in the way. There is zero reason to not use a proper NW ring.

Exactly how bad the results are if you go with a chainline that's too far in also depends on chainstay length and frame alignment.

Answer (score 0):

A quick goolgge reveals: https://bike.shimano.com/en-EU/product/component/deore-m610/FC-M615.html

The specs show the PCD (pitch circle diameter) AKA BCD (bold circle diameter) is 104mm so you can't install a 64mm BCD ring

This crank is also double so you would have to pick either the inner or outer ring position, which will not give you the ideal chain line. There are dedicated single ring cranks available if you are buying a new crank.

Are you converting a 3x9 drivetrain? A common option is to just remove the largest and smallest rings from the triple crank.

Comment: I know what PCD and BCD mean, those definitions were not necessary, also the crankset information is incomplete on the Shimano's website because it has a 24T chainring which not exists in 104 mm but in 64 mm.

Comment: The inner ring on this crank is 64 mm bcd. Only the outer is 104. So it would in fact be possible to run a single 28t, though chainline would not be great. Might be able to get a few mm improvement by shifting spacers on the BB.

Comment: 28t on the inner might foul the chain stay.